# Fetch single row based on latest date received

Tags: sql, oracle

I need only the row which has the latest date:

```
wip_entity_id  Date_Received
1234           26/04/2013
1234           22/03/2008
1234           22/01/2009
1234           22/01/2009
1234           22/02/2006
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use sub-select query in above scenario:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM your_table_name
             ORDER BY Date_Received DESC )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from tbl where Date_Received = (select max(Date_Received) from tbl);
```

Comment: This is what is known as a correlated sub-query and tends to be bad idea. The sub-query will need to evaluated once for each row returned by the outer query. Not cool!

Comment: I believe that the above query is not a correlated sub query ,its a normal subquery which will return the latest `date_recieved` value .

Comment: @ninesided can you plz explain how the above query is correlated.

Comment: my mistake, you a correct, it is not correlated, but it will be evaluated once for each row in `tbl`.